# Normality in Todd-Coxeter Algorithm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How is normality reflected in Todd-Coxeter Algorithm tables?

I can think of the generic cases like if there are only 2 indices then the subgroup has index 2 and thus is normal. Same case for p indices if $G$ is a p-group. But the general case eludes me.

I thought about using left/ right cosets, but T-C deals with only right cosets so that's no use; same goes for the normalizer approach. Unless there is some trick to manipulate the table into that of left cosets, but I really doubt it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration of a group $G$ over a subgroup $H$, then $H \unlhd G$ if and only if, in the final completed table, we have $cy = c$ for all cosets $c$ and all generators $y$ of $H$. If you know in advance that $H$ is normal, then you can assume that condition during the enumeration, but usually you will not be able to verify it until the table is complete.

Comment: As you have seen through my previous questions, I am Master to do this algorithm. +1